# Is there a better way to convert two-dimentional array to string?

Tags: c#, linq

For logging purposes, I need to output a double[,] to the log file. So I need to represent the array as a string.

The following code gets the job done using basic C# 1 features, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution using Linq:

```
private static string OneRowPerLine(double[,] numbers)
{
    var ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(var i=numbers.GetLowerBound(0);i<=numbers.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
    {
        for (var j = numbers.GetLowerBound(1); j <= numbers.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            if(j>numbers.GetLowerBound(1))
            {
                ret.Append(",");
            }
            ret.Append(numbers[i, j]);
        }
        ret.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I think there may be bugs in your code. Specifically in the dimension parameters of some of the `GetLowerBound()` parameters. Based on a quick glance, it should be:

```
private static string OneRowPerLine(double[,] numbers)
{
    var ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(var i=numbers.GetLowerBound(0);i<=numbers.GetUpperBound(0);i++)
    {
        for (var j = numbers.GetLowerBound(1); j <= numbers.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        {
            if(j>numbers.GetLowerBound(1))
            {
                ret.Append(",");
            }
            ret.Append(numbers[i, j]);
        }
        ret.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
```

I'll update this answer in a moment with some enhancements, but wanted to get this bit out of the way.

**EDIT: here's a pair of methods which will do it a little more generically and without LINQ.** It does employ generics (`<T>`) and extension methods (`this`), one of which is an iterator (`yield return`):

```
    private static string OneRowPerLine<T>(this T[,] numbers)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers.FormatOneRow());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> FormatOneRow<T>(this T[,] numbers)
    {
        for (var i = numbers.GetLowerBound(0); i <= numbers.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            var row = new T[numbers.GetLength(1)];

            for (var j = numbers.GetLowerBound(1); j <= numbers.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                row[j] = numbers[i, j];
            }

            yield return string.Join(",", row);
        }
    }
```

call like this:

```
    double[,] stuff = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};
    Console.WriteLine(stuff.OneRowPerLine());
```

Comment: I have fixed the bugs in my code.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

"Better"?  I don't know.  There is a **different** way to deal with this in LINQ.  You can use `Cast<T>` to flatten an `IEnumerable` and the use `Aggregate` to generate a single string from all the elements in the enumerable.  You can then "group" items by line depending on how far you are in the array.  If you have a `double[,]`, you might do something like this:

```
var text = numbers.Cast<double>()
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, i) =>
                                {
                                if ((temp%(numbers.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)) == 0)
                                {
                                    s = s + Environment.NewLine;
                                }
                                temp++;
                                return s + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ", ";
                                });
```

If you like `StringBuilder` better:

```
var text = numbers.Cast<double>()
    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder, (s, i) =>
                                {
                                if ((temp%(numbers.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)) == 0)
                                {
                                    s.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                                }
                                temp++;
                                return s.Append( i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Append(", ");
                                }).ToString();
```

Comment: I think the math here makes is non-obvious what the code actually does and whether it's correct.

Comment: Can you use a StringBuilder instead of a string in you solution?

Comment: @svick Hence my comment about "different"